# How can I exclude enums from code coverage in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, enums, code-coverage

How can I exclude enums from code coverage?

The normal [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] does not work.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  num1: 1,
  num2: 2
}
```

I require enums to be excluded from my code coverage.

EDIT:
Unfortunately I have to maintain a coding standard within my company, so the enums can't be moved into a new project of their own.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a separate project and apply the attribute at the assembly level:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
```

Comment: While this would most probably work, unfortunately my company's coding standard won't approve of moving enums only into a new project.